# Joined aggregate function update?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to denormalize an aggregate bit of data for performance, but can't figure out how to get the aggregation working...

```
CREATE TABLE brands (
    id SERIAL, 
    name TEXT,
    total INTEGER,
    unitcount INTEGER
)   

CREATE TABLE items (
    brandid INTEGER,
    id SERIAL,
    unitvalue INTEGER
)


UPDATE brands SET b.total  = i.sumScore,
b.unitcount = i.unitcount
FROM brands b
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT brandid,
          SUM(unitvalue) sumScore,
          COUNT(unitvalue) unitcount
        FROM items
        group by brandid
    ) as a
    ON i.brandid = b.id
```

This updates EVERY record in brand with the same values, despite the inner join query showing a correct table set of distinct values for each brand.  How can I get that correlated?

Answer (score 0):

please try

```
UPDATE brands b 
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT brandid,SUM(unitvalue) value_to_update,COUNT(unitvalue) cnt 
        FROM items GROUP BY brandid) abc
    ON b.id=abc.brandid 
SET b.total=abc.value_to_update,b.unitcount=abc.cnt
```